# Allowed characters in Prometheus label values

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am thinking of writing my own Prometheus Exporter in node.js. I want to use simple template literals for this. So think of code like this:

```
const bar = `value"` // User input from outside.
let payload = ""
payload += "# HELP my_great_metric Awesome description\n"
payload += "# TYPE my_great_metric gauge\n"
payload += `my_great_metric{foo="${bar}"} 0\n`
```

This would break when Prometheus attempts to scrape the endpoint, because the label value (in variable `bar`) contains double quotation marks, which is apparently used to delimit the label value. This could easily be solved by filtering it.

I've looked up the Prometheus documentation https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels. It says `Label values may contain any Unicode characters.`. I also did some Google research, but could not find something suitable to my use case, handling user-provided label values.

Do I have a misunderstanding, or is it `any Unicode characters` except for the double quotation marks? Are there other characters I need to look out for? Or is there maybe a better approach to handling user-provided label values?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I've never encountered quotes in labels, by it seems you would be OK, if you simply escape it with ``\``. Additionally, you probably should pay attention to `\n` symbol in the input.

Comment: Also, you can use `promtool` to check validity of the exposed data.